# Multivariate Hensel's Lemma

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, p-adic-number-theory, hensels-lemma

Suppose we have a single variable polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Z}_p\subset \mathbb{Q}_p$ and we have its root $\alpha$ over the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$, $f(\alpha)=0$ mod $p$. By Hensel's Lemma we can lift the solution to a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p\subset \mathbb{Q}_p$. The multivariate Hensel's lemma that I checked is stated in the following PDFs.

https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/multivarhensel.pdf, [http://people.math.harvard.edu/~yifei/Hensel_lemma.pdf](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eyifei/Hensel_lemma.pdf)

The thing that I want to solve now is, suppose we have an multivariate polynomial equation over the finite fields $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $\bar{\alpha}=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ as the root, $f(\bar{\alpha})=0$ mod $p$. Can we lift this to a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p\subset \mathbb{Q}_p$? I am not getting how to use the multivariate Hensel's Lemma to solve this problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: The simplest sufficient condition is to check that $(\nabla f)(\alpha)$ is invertible (which only depends on the residue class of $\alpha$).

Comment: Can you please explain a little, why are you saying so.. I think you are referring to the hensel's lemma from the second PDF right?

Comment: @Mindlack If you are referring to the second pdf theorem 1.11 then it makes sense. Is it that?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.

Comment: Merely having $f(\overline{\alpha}) \equiv 0 \bmod p$ is insufficient to expect a lifting to a root in $\mathbf Z_p^n$, even in the case $n = 1$: the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ has a root in $\mathbf F_2$ but it does not lift to a root in $\mathbf Z_2$ since there is not a root mod $4$. You need an *extra condition* of nondegeneracy of some kind, either mod $p$ or in terms of $p$-adic absolute values.  See Examples 2.2, 2.3, and 3.4 in the first link for examples when $n=2$.  Do you "get" how to use the single-variable Hensel's lemma?

Comment: @kCd Thanks for pointing out.. The reason why $x^2+1$ is not getting lifted mod 4 is because the differentiation of the function is 0 mod 2, where as single variable hensel's lemma requires this to be non zero. This points are missing in the second pdf. But the things stated in the first one is not quite clear to me. Like for the examples you stated from pdf 1 are not clear. For multivariates what extra condiiton do we need? Can you help?

Comment: Actually the hensel's lemma in pdf 1 is not quite clear to me

Comment: The single-variable Hensel's lemma for a polynomial $f(x)$ in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$ does *not* require $f'(\alpha) \not\equiv 0 \bmod p$.  If $|f(\alpha)|_p < |f'(\alpha)|_p^2$ then there is a $p$-adic root of $f(x)$ near $\alpha$ in $\mathbf Z_p$. Consider $f(x) = x^2 + 7$. You would say the $2$-adic Hensel's lemma can't be used on $f(x)$, but that is wrong: $|f(1)|_2 = 1/8 < |f'(1)^2|_2 = 1/4$, so there is a root $\beta \in \mathbf Z_2$ of $f(x)$ such that $\beta \equiv \alpha \bmod 2$ (there are two such roots, and you get a unique root if you say $\beta \equiv \alpha \bmod 4$).

Comment: Theorem 1.1 in the 1st pdf is a more general Hensel's lemma in 1 variable. Example 2.2 with $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 4$ uses the simplest form of the one-variable Hensel's lemma (which you know) on $f(x,3)$ in $\mathbf Z_7[x]$ and on $f(1,y)$ in $\mathbf Z_7[y]$. Example 2.3 with $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 21$ uses a more general Hensel's lemma on $f(x,2)$ in $\mathbf Z_2[x]$.  The multivariable Hensel's lemma in Theorem 3.3 uses Jacobians (determinant of derivative matrix - page 3 top) in place of the scalar $f'(\alpha)$. An easier (less interesting) version with a partial derivative is Theorem 2.1.

Comment: What about the hensel's lemma in the second pdf?

Comment: What about it? It is Theorem 1.11 and is about polynomials over a ring $R$ complete with respect to an ideal $\mathfrak a$ (like $R = \mathbf Z_p$ and $\mathfrak a = p\mathbf Z_p$). The proof in Section 3 uses the inverse function theorem in a ring of formal power series over $R$. The matrix $J_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf f)$ there is the derivative matrix $D\mathbf f(\mathbf a)$ in the 1st pdf. The condition $\mathbf f(\mathbf a) \equiv 0 \bmod \det(J_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf f))^2\mathfrak a$ in Theorem 1.11 is analogous to $||\mathbf f(\mathbf a)|| < |J_{\mathbf f}(\mathbf a)|^2$ in the 1st pdf.

Comment: What is written as $\det(J_{\mathbf a}(\mathbf f))$ in the 2nd pdf is written as $J_{\mathbf f}(\mathbf a)$ in the 1st pdf.  There is not always uniform agreement on whether the term "Jacobian" should refer to the matrix of partial derivatives or to the determinant of that matrix, and that's why the same letter $J$ is denoting different things (a determinant of a matrix of partial derivatives in the 1st pdf and a matrix of partial derivatives in the 2nd pdf).